# Set Repeat days of week alarm in android

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

Can somebody give good logic for set repeat days of week alarm? I have done weekly Alarm by using

```java
alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, AlarmHrsInInt);
alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, AlarmMinsInInt);
alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, amorpm);

Long alarmTime = alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis();

Intent intent = new Intent(Alarm.this, AlarmReciever.class);
intent.putExtra("keyValue", key);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Alarm.this, key, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, 7*1440*60000 , pi);
```

The alarm trigger on time and after 7 days it automatically triggers at that time.

But my requirement is I want to choose days rather than just 7 days.

Something like every Monday, Tuesday, Thursday at 9:00 AM - Alarm should trigger automatically. How do I go about doing this in setRepeating?

Can somebody help me out with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These questions talk about the same thing as you want. Those answers will be helpful:

You just need to specify the day to start it and then repeat it every 7 days. There are few ways specified in answers on given questions:

[How can i get the repeat alarm for week days using alarm manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272295/how-can-i-get-the-repeat-alarm-for-week-days-using-alarm-manager)

[Android Notification on specific weekday goes off directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156950/android-notification-on-specific-weekday-goes-off-directly)

[how to repeat alarm week day on in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507901/how-to-repeat-alarm-week-day-on-in-android)

**Update:**

In your comment you said

> How to set the triggerAtMillis part in setRepeating. say for example today is Tuesday, I choose weekly Monday, Wednesday, Friday. - What do I put for Wednesday ?

What I understood that that if today is Tuesday, how to set alarm for lets say Wednesday repeating, right? First of all yes you can use mulltiple id's to set alarms for each day separately.

Then you can add `alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, week);` line to your existing code. Based on the week day( from 1-7) it repeats for that day. You can pass it into a function as parameter. Like:

```
    setAlarm(2); //set the alarm for this day of the week

    public void setAlarm(int dayOfWeek) {
        // Add this day of the week line to your existing code
        alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);

        alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, AlarmHrsInInt);
        alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, AlarmMinsInInt);
        alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, amorpm);

        Long alarmTime = alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
        //Also change the time to 24 hours.
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 , pi); 
}
```

I've taken the example from one of above question. Hope its more clear now.

Comment: You mean to say I have to set different ID for different alarm days. But how to set the triggerAtMillis part in setRepeating.

say for example today is Tuesday, I choose weekly Monday, Wednesday, Friday. - What do I put for Wednesday trigger 1 day from current time?

Comment: Yes different ID for different alarms. For your second part, see the updated answer.

Comment: @Shobit Puri I want to set alarm on week days and above example works but how to set weekly like every tuesday, wednesday. If i set trigger time to 7 days then if next day is tuesday then it doesnt work. can you help?

Comment: Mainly, because i have to set alarm every 1/2/3 weeks on week days so i have to play with trigger time

Comment: @droid_dev You want to set alarm for each day on weekdays or like every tuesday etc

Comment: It can either each day or every tuesday. Both the conditions can be available.

Comment: The alarm will trigger immediately if you set an alarm for tomorrow or other day other than today.

Comment: what does the `am` and `pi` stand for?

Answer (score 6):

To set repeat alarm for week days,use below code. Hope this is helpful.

```
        Calendar calender= Calendar.getInstance();

        calender.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, weekNo);  //here pass week number
        calender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);  //pass hour which you have select
        calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);  //pass min which you have select
        calender.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calender.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        now.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        now.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        if (calender.before(now)) {    //this condition is used for future reminder that means your reminder not fire for past time
            calender.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
        }

        final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();  //this id is used to set multiple alarms

        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, YourServiceClass.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, _id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calender.getTimeInMillis(), 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if (Monday.isChecked()) {
                        setalarm(2);
                    } else if (Tuesday.isChecked()) {
                        setalarm(3);
                    } else if (Wednesday.isChecked()) {
                        setalarm(4);
                    } else if (Thursday.isChecked()) {
                        setalarm(5);
                    } else if (Friday.isChecked()) {
                        setalarm(6);
                    } else if (Saturday.isChecked()) {
                        setalarm(7);
                    } else if (Sunday.isChecked()) {
                        setalarm(1);
                    }

public void setalarm(int weekno) {

        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, weekno);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,


     cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: I may be mistaken, but it seems like this is the only answer to have the alarm repeat in a week, not the next day.

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NotificationReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
                                                          1,
                                                          intent1,
                                                          PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
java.util.Calendar calendar1 = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

calendar1.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,
              Calendar.MONDAY);
calendar1.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,
              22);
calendar1.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE,
              8);
calendar1.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND,
              0);

alarmManager1.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent1);
```