# How to set alarm to go-off on certain days of the week?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I found this:
[Set Repeat days of week alarm in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894067/set-repeat-days-of-week-alarm-in-android)

Is there any other way? Can I do it using only one alarm manager or do I have to use another alarm manager for each day?

Comment: I would use one daily alarm and then check whether it's the correct day.

Comment: I would schedule a non repeating alarm and when it "rings" I would determine when the next one should go off, schedule a non repeat again and so on.