# How to create multiple alarms on a day and this will repeat on selected week days?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I need to configure a reminder that will happens multiple times on selected week days.

For example:

Alarm Frequency: 2 hours
Week Days: Monday, Thursday

If user select Monday and Thursday, and a frequency of 2 hours; the alarm must repeat each 2 hours only on Monday and Thursday.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to create an alarm.

Please take a look at the link below,

http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

EDIT:

If you want to repeat it Multiple times on a selected weekdays, then please take a look at the following link,

[Set Repeat days of week alarm in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894067/set-repeat-days-of-week-alarm-in-android)

Comment: No man.. Alarm can be set with a trigger time and repeat if you set setRepeat. 
But I don't know how to do the way I mentioned on question: Multiple times a day and only happens on selected weekdays.

Comment: @JonasOliveira: I have added a new link for you. See if it works out for you. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, but I have not find yet how I will implement my alarms. This logic is kind complicated. Thank you for your help!